# Is it valid to write in pg_hba.conf file while server is running?

Tags: postgresql

While the server is running, is it okay to write or rewrite or update the pg_hba.conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Just don't add any syntax errors.

Once you are done, run `SELECT pg_reload_conf();` to read the new definitions. Check the log file for errors, since they would prevent the server from restarting.